# Moving or Syncing Bucket from user to another user's bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to move or sync the bucket, including the files, from one user's to another user's bucket? Can it be done with gsutil?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read access to the source bucket and all of its objects you can use gsutil rsync for this purpose. I suggest using gsutil -m rsync, to parallelize the operation.

Comment: how do you make the other user to have read access to the source bucket? I have tried using the command such as gsutil -m rsync gs://testqwer gs://test123, in which testqwer is my bucket and test123 is the bucket from other user, in which the project i have been given the owner role for it

Comment: `gsutil -m defacl ch -u user@domain.com:R gs://test123` to ensure new objects are accessible, then `gsutil -m acl ch -u user@domain.com:R gs://test123/**` to update the existing objects.